# Doctrine 2 - Unable to access newly created record (outside of Doctrine)

Tags: php, wordpress, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

A few key notes on my environment:

- I have an app that is built on Wordpress and we're using Doctrine as our ORM.
- In order to maintain WP's integrity, we let WP handle the creation of users
- Every WP object and custom object is mapped properly through Doctrine.

The situation is:

```
// 1. Create a user via **WP** function (which returns ID)
$wp_user_id = wp_insert_user($wp_user_array);

// 2. Then, I need to immediately retrieve that user object via Doctrine
$wp_user = $MyDb->em->getRepository('WpUsers')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$wp_user_id));

// 3. RESULT = NULL
```

**The object is not found, presumably because the Entity is cached or stored in memory somewhere by Doctrine.**

How can I force Doctrine to go look at the DB and get this newly created user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this ended up being fairly simple. After trying `clear()`, `refresh()` and force clearing Doctrine's cache I was running out of options.

It turns out what I had to do to get Doctrine to check that the new record was created, is close and open the connection:

```
$this->_em->getConnection()->close();
$this->_em->getConnection()->connect();
```

Not the most ideal solution, I know, but it works and I have been debugging this for five days now!

Answer (score 0):

You can clear doctrine cache with

```
EntityManager::clear()
```

See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html (search for clear method)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but when I add `$MyDb->em->clear();` before attempting to retrieve the record, it still can't find them. I know it's in the DB (seen through debugging), Doctrine just can't access it. **Am I clearing it properly?**

Comment: Just to correct - In your question you have `$MyDb->em..` but now there is `$TilDb->em...`. Clear method actually detaches all object from repository. One more idea. Is doctrine and wordpress using same connection? If not, can you try doing pure query on doctrine connection after you insert on wordpress connection?

Comment: Yes the name change was just to make the question more generic. WP and Doctrine are using the same DB. I would rather avoid requesting it via DQL as I'm not sure that will return an object as the result will it?

Comment: If you use DQL or find methods doesn't matter. You can choose how you want your results from DQL query (`->getResult()` - returns objects, `->getArrayResult()`- returns array and etc.). Just to be sure, by same connection i don't mean same user credentials but same connection object resource.

Can you try doing query with dql if that helps?

Comment: Well, no, not the same connection, WP has it's own DB access, while I am using Doctrine. Tried with DQL and still no luck. Not sure that I am clearing the cache correctly, or if I am, then the cache is not the issue..

Comment: Even when I try get all records in the table via Doctrine, it still only shows the records pre-WP insert.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, the solution ended up being pretty simple, see my answer above :)